# Track and store button clicks

Tags: button, click, counter, store, reset

I would like to count the number of times an specific button is pressed by any user and then use that value to modify the opacity of an image. Every time the opacity is 100, I would like to reset the count and start from 0 again.

I am a beginner and I am not sure which way would be the easiest one. I've created a database for my website but I don't know if it's indispensable for doing this. Any advise? Thanks.

Comment: Some more context would be useful to answer this. What languages/frameworks are you using? Do you have any existing code?

Comment: I am using PHP, SQL and Fat Free Framework. I don't have any code because I don't know which approach I should take. I've read that you can do something similiar using jquery but I am not sure if that would suit my needs.

Comment: @Aniket Schneider This is what I have so far:  `<input type="button" value="Click" id="btn"/>  <input id="counting" type = "text" hidden/>  <img src="" id="image" style="opacity: 0;">  <script> 
 var x = 0;  function count() {  if(x<100){  x += 1;  }else{  x=0;  } 
 document.getElementById("counting").value = x;  var element = 
 document.getElementById("image");  element.style.opacity = (x/100);  } 
 $('#btn').click(  function() {  count();  });  </script>`

Comment: As far as I can tell that code works!  I've put it into jsfiddle here with a couple small modifications: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/162767/  Are you seeing any errors in your Javascript console?

Comment: @AniketSchneider Yes, it does. How can I store the number of clicks in the database and update it? Thanks for your help.